# Нужно несколько раз выполнить одинаковый участок кода в разных местах

Tags: php

Есть код, допустим этот:

```
<?php
$a="переменная А ";
$b="переменная Б";
for ($x=a; $x<q; $x++) echo $$x.' ';
?>
```

Его нужно много раз повторять в разных местах. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вам в первый класс программирования, если честно, но вообще есть такая вещь, как функции. Использовать так:

```
<?php
// определяем нашу функцию
function myfunc(){
  $a="переменная А ";
  $b="переменная Б";
  for ($x=a; $x<q; $x++) echo $$x.' ';
}
// используем ее столько раз, сколько нужно
myfunc();
myfunc();
?>
```

Comment: ну и зачем вы все на тарелочке подали?

Comment: @Руслан я не страдаю троллингом в профессиональных сообществах. Возможно, ему программирование второй раз в жизни понадобилось и после не пригодится больше никогда.

Comment: ну, у каждого свой подход)))